# Puppet permissions denied creating directory?

Tags: puppet

I'm applying a `.pp` config file via `puppet agent -t`.

When the following part of the config runs I get a permission error:

```
file { "/opt/2klic":
  ensure => directory,
}
```

> Error: Could not set 'directory' on ensure: Permission denied @
>   dir_s_mkdir - /opt/2klic at
>   /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/manifests/site.pp:20
>   Error: Could not set 'directory' on ensure: Permission denied @
>   dir_s_mkdir - /opt/2klic at
>   /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/manifests/site.pp:20
>   Wrapped exception: Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /opt/2klic Error:
>   /Stage[main]/Main/Node[default]/File[/opt/2klic]/ensure: change from
>   absent to directory failed: Could not set 'directory' on ensure:
>   Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /opt/2klic at
>   /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/manifests/site.pp:20

I attempted to fix the issue by adding the user puppet to the sudo group:

```
sudo usermod -a -G sudo puppet
```

But it doesn't fix the permission issue.

Comment: Are you not running Puppet as root or with elevated privileges?

Comment: @MattSchuchard it isn't possible to use `sudo` on the device I installed puppet on but the user I'm using is in the sudo group.

Comment: Running Puppet not as root or without sudo is kind of problematic. I do it sometimes for short demos/presentations, but in general I wouldn't expect a standard use case for Puppet to function without elevated privileges.

Comment: Even running Puppet as root is not a cure-all.  There are forms of access control that can still apply, such as SELinux running in enforcing mode, or mount options for the filesystem.

Comment: Additionally, just having the user be a member of some particular group does not inherently grant administrative privileges.  The significance of a 'sudo' group is presumably that the `sudo` command is configured to allow members of that group to run `sudo`, and to grant particular privileges to them.  That's kinda pointless if the user really can't run `sudo` on the device for some other reason.

Comment: If it isn't possible to use `sudo` then the `sudo` group is meaningless.  no matter what, you need to run `puppet` as a user that has permissions to make the changes you wish it to make.  To have puppet create a directory in `/opt`, you need to run puppet as a user who has permission to create a directory in `/opt`.  Generally, that means running as `root`.